# Django with Postgresql permissions?

Tags: django, apache, postgresql, permissions

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04

For their purposes, they use SQLite, and run these commands to set up the permissions for the database:

```
chmod 664 ~/myproject/db.sqlite3
```

And:

```
sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject/db.sqlite3
sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject
```

For my project, I use Postgresql, which is quite different it seems to me. As expected, I run into issues concerning the database permissions. If I go to my Django admin site, I get these:

```
OperationalError at /admin/
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://46.101.181.13/admin/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Exception Location: /home/antoni4040/django_project/django_project_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 164
Python Executable:  /home/antoni4040/django_project/django_project_env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/home/antoni4040/django_project',
 '/home/antoni4040/django_project/django_project_env/lib/python35.zip',
 '/home/antoni4040/django_project/django_project_env/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/antoni4040/django_project/django_project_env/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/antoni4040/django_project/django_project_env/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/antoni4040/django_project/django_project_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 10 Jun 2016 12:15:59 +0000
```

How can I setup the permissions(or whatever) so that the database starts working? Thank you.

**Edit:**
settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'jokes_database',
        'USER': 'antoni4040',
        'PASSWORD': 'noneedtoknowthat',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to setup the DATABASES in settings.py as described in the django documentation.

Comment: Added the code, take a look.

Comment: "Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: How do I set that?

Comment: nothing for you to set. Something for you to read and then check

Comment: You could say that I'm a total newbie to anything that has to do with postgresql, I've been using it since Monday...

Comment: Generally you can find out if postgresql is running by ps -ef | grep post

Comment: Is postgres running? Did you create a postgres user? Can you connect to postgres via psql from the command line? How does the DB part of your settings look like?

Comment: This command (sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status) shows me that it's active, but psql gives me an error that it can't connect to server etc. The DB settings are in the answer.

Comment: Never mind, I purged the postgresql installation, reinstalled, recreated the database, changed a few settings and now it's working just fine...